# extjs autoHeight in container with autoScroll does not work

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I have two containers and I need to add a scrollbar in one of them, I actually do that but only works when I put height directly, I need the height to adjust the window size.

I have tried to add autoHeight property instead of height but does not seems to work.

Here is the code:

```
{
    xtype: 'container',//This is a parent container
    layout: {
    type: 'hbox',
    align: 'stretch'
    },
    items: [
    {
        xtype: 'container',
        flex: 0.8,
        autoScroll: true, // this works with height but not with autoHeight
        //height: 610,
        layout: 'fit',
        defaults: {
        anchor: '100%',
        labelAlign: 'top'
     },
     style:{
        "background-color" : '#1b536c',
     },
     items: [
         {
            xtype: 'dataview',
            flex: 1,
            scroll: 'vertical',
            tpl: 'some tpl',
            store:['some store'],
            anchor: '100%',
            itemSelector: '.nav-main'
        }
     ]},
     {
         xtype: 'container',
         flex: 3.2,
         margins: '0 25 0 25',
         defaults: {
             anchor: '100%',
             labelAlign: 'top'
          },
         layout: 'anchor',
         items: [
            //Some form components
         ]
      }
}
```

Comment: Can you put runnable code in some fiddle ?

Comment: I don't know how

Comment: I create fiddle(https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2vik) based on your code and it work for me. Maybe your parent container(or viewport) hasn't height or has specific layout.